# Помогите разобраться в синтаксисе Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Вот конкретно пример который вызывает у меня затруднения:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_tasks, menu)

        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView

        searchView.onQueryTextChanged {
            viewModel.searchQuery.value = it
        }
    }
```

Самая непонятная часть:

```
inline fun SearchView.onQueryTextChanged(crossinline listener: (String) -> Unit) {
    this.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            listener(newText.orEmpty())
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

Вопросы:
Почему вызов функции происходит без обычных скобок ()?

Что конкретно передается и возвращается при вызове метода? или иначе говоря что Это Такое?:

```
searchView.onQueryTextChanged {
            viewModel.searchQuery.value = it
        }
```

И что это значит?:

```
crossinline listener: (String) -> Unit
//
listener(newText.orEmpty())
```

Comment: Задал тот же вопрос на корявом английском и получил минус. Напишите если что то не так с вопросом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Высокоуровневые функции и лямбды](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/lambdas.html)

Если первым и единственным параметром в функцию передается лямбда, то можно не писать `()`, а сразу писать `{ a, b -> a + b }`, где `a` и `b` параметры передаваемые в лямбду.

Если последним параметром передается лямбда, то её так же можно вынести в фигурные скобки.

```
searchView.onQueryTextChanged {
    viewModel.searchQuery.value = it
}
```

`onQueryTextChanged` имеет параметр типа `f: (T) -> Unit`.
`it` это ключевое слово которое можно использовать вместо явного указания параметра лямбды.
Так же можно было бы написать:

```
searchView.onQueryTextChanged { query ->
    viewModel.searchQuery.value = query
}


crossinline listener: (String) -> Unit
//
listener(newText.orEmpty())
```

С этим еще не сталкивался, но в доке пишут, что это нужно в `inline` функциях.
Можно почитать об этом [тут](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns).

Comment: То есть это по сути как если бы ты заменил вызов listener в onQueryTextChange выражением в фигурных скобках, так?                                                                                                                         
   override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            viewModel. searchQuery. value = newText 
            return true
        }

Comment: @KyloFernao, то, что находится в лямбде(фигурных скобках) это по сути безымянная функция которая когда нибудь вызовется и произойдет выполнение того, что находится внутри нее. Это еще называют callback.

Comment: Из того что я понял после чтения документации inline позволяет переданной функции становиться частью того кода в котором оно вызывается. То есть когда вызывается return внутри inline функции, завершается внешняя функция.